# Prepared Statement INSERT JDBC MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am getting an error on doing ' mvn tomcat:run " . The error I am getting is:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO ibstechc_dev.device (key, ip_address, type, name)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, ip_address, type, name)  VALUES ('abcd', 'abcd', 1234, 'abcd')' at line 1

root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO ibstechc_dev.device (key, ip_address, type, name)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, ip_address, type, name)  VALUES ('abcd', 'abcd', 1234, 'abcd')' at line 1
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:237)
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72
```

My code segment is:

```
 List<Device> devices = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
            "select * from xyz.device a,xyz.user_device b "
                    + "where b.user_id = ? and a.device_id = b.device_id and "
                    + "a.type = ?",
            new Object[]{userId,type},
            new RowMapper<Device>() {
 public Device mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Device device = new Device();

                    device.setId(Long.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)));
                    device.setKey(rs.getString(2));
                device.setIPAddress(rs.getString(3));
                    device.setType(rs.getInt(4));
                    device.setName(rs.getString(5));
                        return device;
                }
            });
      System.out.println("Found for user..." + userId);
      return devices;
}

public void create(Device device) {
    this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO xyz.device (key, ip_address, type, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 

                    new Object[]{device.getKey(), device.getIPAddress(), device.getType(), device.getName()});              
        }
        public void delete(Device device) {
            this.jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM xyz.device WHERE device_id = ?", new Object[] {device.getId()});      
        }

        public void update(Device device) {
            this.jdbcTemplate.update(
                    "UPDATE xyz.device SET key = ?, ip_address = ?, type = ?, name =? WHERE device_id = ?", new Object[]{device.getId(),device.getKey(), device.getIPAddress(), device.getType(), device.getName()});
```

And my Debug.java code is:

```
public String getNavBarData(){
      Device device = new Device();
      device.setKey("abcd");
      device.setIPAddress("abcd");
      device.setType(1234);
      device.setName("abcd");


        deviceDao.create(device);
        return "";
```

The MySQL table has the same columns as in my code above with NOT NULL for each field. I have used the same code for a different functionality and it works there. Why am I getting this error for this one? Pls. Help.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try adding quotation marks around the question marks

Comment: Tried it - it's flagged by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in Mysql. Therefore you either rename the column (which is better in a long run) or use back ticks around it.

That being said you insert statement should look like this

```sql
INSERT INTO xyz.device (`key`, ip_address, type, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                        ^   ^
```

The same goes to your update statement

```
UPDATE xyz.device SET `key` = ?, ip_address = ?, type = ?, name =? WHERE device_id = ?
                      ^   ^
```

Comment: @user2480526 It can't be **the same error**. Are you sure you used back tick character and not single quotes? Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7071) demo. Uncomment the last insert and click `Build schema` you'll get your error. Or another explanation is that you have other places in your code where you have `key` without back ticks.

Comment: Done. I don't have the reputation to upvote your answer (yet). But thanks again.

Comment: @user2480526 Now you can :)

Comment: Thanks! I ended up enclosing them all in back ticks.